# How to move this text onto another line

Tags: html, css

I got this text that I want to move onto Another line,

This is how it's looking like now,

[image]

This is how I want it,

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="header">
        <p>
        <img class="header-image" src="http://www.nab.com.au/content/dam/nab/personal/credit-cards/apply-for-a-credit-card/images/icon-apply-online.gif" />
        <span id="header-text-1">Helo00oo To</span>
        <span id="header-text-2">FruitLand</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
        <div id="body-title">Fruit Login</div>
        <div id="box-one"> Radio List with 2 radio buttons</div>
        <div id="box-two"> CheckBox</div>
        <div id="box-three">Textboxes x 2</div>
        <div id="body-footer">Textboxes x 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header-image {
vertical-align: text-top;
}

#header-text-2{
    font-size: 2.6em;
    line-height: 0.8em;
}
```

Here's the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u9Qa9/1/) if you want to try -  should work on all browsers.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u9Qa9/2/  check this out

Comment: You can use `<br/>` may be.

Comment: Why negative vote, I beg you for reason ?

Comment: Why are you using spans if you want them to be on separate lines?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `position:relative`. Add this:

```
#header-text-2{
    font-size: 2.6em;
    line-height: 0.8em;
    position:relative;
    top:34px;
    left:-86px;
}
```

And then adjust to your prefered position playing with `top` and `left` rules

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u9Qa9/3/)

Answer (score 1):

How is the following. Display your image as a block, but float it to the left. Clear the float by giving `overflow:hidden` to the paragraph.

Display both of your span elements as blocks, they'll line up one beneath the other, but still clearing the image, using `overflow:hidden` again:

```
#header p{
    overflow:hidden;
}
.header-image {
    vertical-align: text-top;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
#header-text-1, #header-text-2{
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Pad out your `<span>`s as you see fit.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/u9Qa9/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try please and done

```
#header
{
width:100%; 
    float:left ;   
}
.header-image {
vertical-align: text-top;
    float:left;
}
#header-text-1
{
       width:50%; 
    float:left;

}
#header-text-2{
    font-size: 2.6em;
    line-height: 0.8em;
    width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Omar Sedki's solution. An improvement is:

```
.header-image {
    float:left
}
#header-text-2 {
    display:block;
}
#body {
    clear: left;
}
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sfarsaci/thHuR/).

`#body { clear: left;}`
is to keep "Fruit Login" under the image